Wrong notification system in KDE Plasma (again)
I'm using KDE Plasma on Suse Tumbleweed but the notifications are not working any more. When I try to configure the notifications using the Configuration app, I'm told that

Notifications are currently provided by 'GNOME cinnamon' instead of Plasma.

I found wrong-notification-system-in-kde-plasma and applied the accepted answer solution to my problem
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/
ln -s /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.plasma.Notifications.service \
  ~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.plasma.Notifications.service

followed by a restart but nothing changed, in the configuration app I still have

Notifications are currently provided by 'GNOME cinnamon' instead of Plasma.

What should I do the have notifications working as they used to do?

Addendum
Just because dbus is involved,
$ sudo systemctl status dbus
● dbus-broker.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dbus-broker.service; enabled; preset: >
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/dbus-broker.service.d
             └─block-restart.conf
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-09-06 11:46:03 CEST; 29min ago
 Invocation: 4aaf4a564c6945a395fa85e24111783a
TriggeredBy: ● dbus.socket
       Docs: man:dbus-broker-launch(1)
   Main PID: 1578 (dbus-broker-lau)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 18352)
        CPU: 501ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/dbus-broker.service
             ├─1578 /usr/bin/dbus-broker-launch --scope system --audit
             └─1579 dbus-broker --log 4 --controller 9 --machine-id cbd4a50f23a94e8>

Sep 06 11:46:03 localhost systemd[1]: Starting D-Bus System Message Bus...
Sep 06 11:46:03 localhost systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Sep 06 11:46:03 localhost dbus-broker-launch[1578]: Ready


Another answer suggests to solve my problem intervening on the KDE Plasma side of the issue, I solved it intervening on the Cinnamon side.
I removed Cinnamon and everything cinnamon spiced from my PC and now everything is  fine.
Not only I have back  the notifications, the benefits did not stop there…
A couple weeks ago I asked "I cannot change the network connection anymore using nm-applet" in which I exposed the problem in the title and a myriad of other problems connected (probably) to bad credentials and when I removed Cinnamon all of these problems went away.

PS — I don't want to blame Cinnamon, I'd rather say that OpenSuse made some sort of blooper while packaging the cinnamon ecosystem.

Definitely make a backup of all your data, settings and config files.
This is because GNOME or Cinnamon is overriding the KDE Plasma notification system.
Try restarting plasma services:
kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell
Start or restart plasma-notifications:
systemctl --user start plasma-notifications
try disable gnome/cinnamon notification.
Remove gnome/cinnamon files from dbus:
rm ~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/org.gnome*
rm ~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/org.cinnamon*

I foud this for reinstall plasma notification components:
sudo zypper install --force plasma5-desktop plasma-framework plasma-nm
You can reinstall the KDE desktop.
sudo apt install --reinstall kde-plasma-desktop
I think this is for suse:
sudo zypper install --force kde-plasma-desktop
Also, check out this post, for me this works on Debian 12.6 and KDE-Plasma.
I can’t log into my KDE desktop over the login screen in Debian, after deleting some packages
If you don't use GNOME, you can uninstall it.
sudo zypper rm gnome-shell gnome-session cinnamon
Restart your sessions dbus settings:
sudo systemctl restart dbus
I would first reinstall KDE, and if it doesn't work, uninstall GNOME and then reinstall KDE again.
